# Populate items in tableView cell from a class model error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following class model for the items. I am displaying itemsName,itemprice in sections. And Addonname and AdddonPrice  in cell based on the index.. the number of sections and the number of cells are coming correctly from the class modal. sections data are also working fine. The problem is to display addon data  into customTableCell.

```
class Cart{

var itemID:AnyObject?
var itemName:AnyObject?
var itemPrice:AnyObject?

var cartAddon:[AnyObject?]


init(itemID:AnyObject?,itemName:AnyObject?,itemPrice:AnyObject?,cartAddon:[AnyObject?]){
    self.itemID = itemID
    self.itemName = itemName
    self.itemPrice = itemPrice
    self.cartAddon = cartAddon

 }

 }

class CartAddon {

    var addonID:Int?
    var addonName:String?
    var addonPrice:Double?

init(addonID:Int?,addonName:String?, addonPrice:Double?){

        self.addonID = addonID
        self.addonName = addonName
        self.addonPrice = addonPrice

  }

}
```

**Tableview code**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


    return cartArray.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cartheadercell") as! cartHeaderCell

    header.ItemnameLbl.text = cartArray[section].itemName as? String
    header.ItemPriceLbl.text = (cartArray[section].itemPrice as! String)

return header


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cartArray[section].cartAddon.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cartcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddonCell

   //error in this part

    let cart: Cart = cartArray[indexPath.row].cartAddon[indexPath.row]
    if let name = cart.cartAddon[indexPath.row]!["AddonName"]{

        cell.AddonNameLbl.text  = (name as! String)
    }


   cell.AddonPriceLbl.text = "£ 0.0"

    return cell
}
```

The data is coming in this form which I have to display is:

```
Optional(9 Inch Thin & Crispy Margarita)
Optional(£3.40)
Optional(1749)
[Optional(Chicos_Pizza.CartAddon), Optional(Chicos_Pizza.CartAddon),     Optional(Chicos_Pizza.CartAddon), Optional(Chicos_Pizza.CartAddon)]
```

Comment: just add `!` to unwrap these values to get rid of Optional

Comment: that not the issue .. see the data carefully. i Only send you wat type of array format i am saving into the class model. now from that i need to display in the given cell . optional. i know to handle it.  @Dravidian

Comment: just checking @NDoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to use `indexPath.section` to access the `Cart` object from array not `indexParh.row`, so change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code like this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cartcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddonCell                
    if let cartAddon = cartArray[indexPath.section].cartAddon[indexPath.row] as? CartAddon, let name = cartAddon.addonName {

        cell.AddonNameLbl.text = name
    }
    else {
        cell.AddonNameLbl.text = "Set here some default value or blank string"
    }
    cell.AddonPriceLbl.text = "£ 0.0"
    return cell
}
```